# In an office JS add-in how can I delete a sheet that I'm not sure its there?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I want to create a sheet with a name that I dont know if its already used. For that reason I need to try to find as sheet with that name and if it exists delte it.

Comment: Do you currently have the code for creating a sheet?

Comment: Wrap the delete in try/catch and just ignore any error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WorksheetCollection.getItemOrNullObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=office-js#getitemornullobject-key-) method to test whether it exists. For more information, see the help [OrNullObject methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-advanced-concepts#42ornullobject-methods).

Example:

```
var dataSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItemOrNullObject("Data"); 

return context.sync()
  .then(function() {
    if (!dataSheet.isNullObject) { 
        // Delete the sheet
    }    
    // Create the sheet
  })
```